# Условие на изменение переменных в SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

В общем такая, задача, у меня есть `DialogFramgent` в котором реализованы настройки приложения, и внизу есть кнопки, `Отмена` и `Применить`. Так вот, если пользователь ничего не изменил в настройках, диалоговое окно закрывается по нажатию на кнопку `Отмена` или нажатием на кнопку `Назад` на устройсте. Если же он изменил что-либо в настройках, и нажал кнопку `Отмена` в конце диалогового окна, то оно закроется, а если он нажмёт кнопку `Назад` на устройстве то нужно вызывать новое диалоговое окно с предложением сохранить или не сохранять. Я все реализовал, единственное, я не могу понять, как мне проверить, изменил ли он что-нибудь? Все изменения идут по `SharedPreferences`. Я так полагаю, что мне в `onBackPressed` нужно сделать условие, что если в `SharedPreferences` внесены изменения чтобы вызывался `DialogAlert` если же нет, то чтобы просто закрывались настройки. Вопрос лишь в том, какое условие я должен сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

На входе в диалог сохраните ваши значения в `Map<String,?> map = prefs.getAll();`, затем в нужный момент сравните `map.equals(prefs.getAll())`. Есть сомнения, но вроде `equals` должен работать как надо.

Comment: В такой форме, в которой я задал вопрос это рабочий ответ. Но там загвоздка в том, что если mEditor.apply я не применяю, то он не регаирует, а если применяю то реагирует, у меня кнопки Отмена и Применить выполняют соответствующие действия. Если юзер изменил настройки и нажал отмена, все закрылось без изменений, если же юзер нажал Применить то вызывается mEditor.apply, применяются все настройки и закрывается окно, в моем случае ваш метод не работает, но как я и сказал, на то как был задан вопрос, это ответ.

Comment: @McDaggen, тогда такой вариант: все изменения вставлять в эту же `Map` вместо эдитора, в конце её сравнить с оригиналом, а в эдитор всё записать и применить уже при сохранении.

Comment: @woesss Пытаюсь осмыслить, не получается)

Comment: @McDaggen, это в дополнение к ответу Jarvis_J. В полученную в начале `Map` записываем изменения, которые делает юзер, тогда в конце, когда мы сравниваем её с преференсами, получаем однозначный результат - есть изменения или нет (до применения `apply()`).

Comment: @woesss так изменения то не вступают в силу, так как `apply` не вызван ни разу. Наш `map` это список всех `String` ключей. Теоретически можно было бы два `map` сделать. Первый, это значение ключей при входе в настройки, а второй такой же, но вызывать его при выходе и сравнивать их, если они одинаковы, значит изменений не произошло, если не одинаковы, значит вызываем диалоговое окно. Но загвоздка в том, что значение ключей не меняется, пока мы не вызовим `apply`, а если вызвать, то настройки будут применяться, даже если пользователь не хочет этого.

Comment: @woesss В общем, я пока что остановился на том, что сделал дополнительный `SharedPreferences` поместил его `Editor` в каждое унаследованное `View` и на `boolean` сделал, если будет вызвано какое-нибудь из имеющихся `View` элементов он станет `true`. И в методе `onCreate` он принимает состояние `false`. Вроде работает как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, при вызове DialogFramgent запоминайте сохраненные настройки, а при нажатии на кнопку "назад" сравнивайте текущие настройки с сохраненными. Если что-то не совпадает, то запрашивайте сохранение

Comment: Сначала хотел так сделать, но `View` элементов более 10, и устанавливать проверку на каждый показалось громоздким.